# Is this a coordinating conjunction connecting to a dependent adverbial clause? Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: conjunctions, compound-complex

This sentence seems to use 'and' to connect an independent clause to a complex sentence (adverbial clause + independent clause).

"Smith said the statute is reserved for “traitors and spies,” **and** while it’s true that espionage refers to spying, the provision Smith was charged under prohibits willful retention of national defense information and has been used to prosecute about a dozen others accused of holding on to classified information over the past five years."

Am I parsing this incorrectly? Is this grammatically correct?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's parsed correctly but is a run-on sentence.  To eliminate the run-on sentence, you could omit your "and" and just start a new sentence there.